# Having trouble setting up Synergy (via Quicksynergy)

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, mouse, synergy

Synergy is an app that allows two or more computers to share a keyboard and mouse.  I have both Synergy and QuickSynergy (the GUI for synergy) installed from the repositories on two computers. One, my "main" box, is running Ubuntu 11.10.  Sitting above it on a shelf is an older laptop running Lubuntu 11.10.  I have watched a couple of youtube videos which attept to walk one through the setup process but so far I have not found one that can help me. I have the required applications installed on both machines and they are connected via my wireless router.  I need to know exactly what to input (and where) on each machine in order to sync my mouse, keyboard, and clipboard between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Synergy user guide](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/running.html) and a [sample configuration file](http://awesomelinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/synergy-configuration-example.html). If you prefer to configure it with a GUI rather than a config file, try the 1.4.5 beta at [Synergy's download page](http://synergy-foss.org/download/).

Comment: Installed the beta package... configured the app, still nothing.

Comment: What happens when you start Synergy? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Synergy from a [package repository for Ubuntu](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-synergy-1-5-1-ubuntu-14-04/).

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synergy
```

Once you have installed the package, you can run `synergyc` for the client, `synergys` for the server and `synergy` for an administration GUI. The administration GUI allows you to configure and run your machine as a server or as a client.

You may find several tutorials in the internet to [use synergy in your Ubuntu](https://codeyarns.com/2015/05/22/how-to-use-synergy-in-ubuntu/).

Answer (score -1):

You can install the Synergy from a [package repository for Ubuntu](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-synergy-1-5-1-ubuntu-14-04/).

```
$ wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install synergy
```

Once you have installed the package, you can run `synergyc` for the client, `synergys` for the server and `synergy` for an administration GUI. The administration GUI allows you to configure and run your machine as a server or as a client.

You may find several tutorials in the internet to [use synergy in your Ubuntu](https://codeyarns.com/2015/05/22/how-to-use-synergy-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please expand your answer. Link-only answers are not of great quality.